# Nine squares are arranged to form a rectangle. Area of smallest square(square P) is 4 unit^2 find areas of square Q and R

Tags: geometry

The figure below shows $9$ squares $A, B, C, D, E , F , P$ (in red) , $Q , R $

The squares are arranged as shown such that they make up a rectangle.

If the area of the tiny square $P$ (shown in red) is $4$ $\text{cm}^2$, find the sum of the areas of squares $Q$ and $R$.

The context of this question is an exercise in imposing linear and quadratic constraints on a set of variables.

By studying the relation between the various squares, I was able to write $9$ equations relating the $9$ unknowns, which are the side lengths of the $9$ squares: $ a,b,c,d,e,f,q, r $ ($p$ is known to be equal to $2$ ).

The nine equations are:

$ a + b + c = f + r $

$ a + e + f = c + r $

$ e = a + p $

$ a = b + p $

$ b = d + p $

$ f = e + q $

$ r = f + q $

$ c = d + b $

$ p = 2 $

I would like to investigate if these $9$ equations lead to a unique solution, or whether additional equations are required to guarantee a solution.

Any helpful comments, hints, or solutions are highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: let $a$ and $p$ be sides of $A$ and $P$, you can express sides of $B,D,C,E,Q,F$ in terms of $a,p$ (in the given order). After that you should have two expression for side of $R$...

Comment: "please answer it" is like an order ! Work, and show you have worked

Comment: Which one among P and Q is the smallest one ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the picture is not drawn in scale, $P$ is 4 times smaller than $Q$. The configuration is essentially the smallest simple perfect squared rectangle.

Comment: @achille hui Thanks. Btw, I have found this [seminal article](https://carlo-hamalainen.net/stuff/Brooks,%20Smith,%20SThe%20Dissection%20of%20Rectangles%20Into%20Squares%20R.%20L.%20Brooks,%20C.%20A.%20B.%20Smith,%20A.%20H.%20Stone%20&%20W.%20T.%20Tuttetone,%20Tutte%20-%20The%20dissection%20of%20rectangles%20into%20squares%20%281940%29.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, the link you have doesn't work but I some how manage to get the underlying article.

Answer (score 1):

The given equations relating the side lengths do not guarantee a unique solution.  Additional equations are needed, and they are

$ a + e = q + d + b $

$ e + d = a + b $

With this, the system of $11$ equations in the $9$ unknowns has a unique solution, and it is

$a = 18$

$b = 16$

$c = 30$

$ d = 14 $

$ e = 20 $

$ f = 28 $

$ p = 2 $

$ q = 8 $

$ r = 36 $

Therefore, the sum of areas of squares $Q$ and $R$ is $ 8^2 + 36^2 = \boxed{1360} $