# Assembling $10$ squares to form a rectangle

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, puzzle

This question is closely related to this [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661098/nine-squares-are-arranged-to-form-a-rectangle-area-of-smallest-squaresquare-p/4661762#4661762).  The figure below shows the relative positions of $10$ rectangles, which together fit within the big (boundary) rectangle.  The purpose of this exercise is to find if it is possible for rectangles $A$ through $J$ to be squares.  If that's possible, find the side lengths of all the squares if square $E$ has a side length of $12$.

[image]

My attempt:

Using the provided schematic, and denoting the side lengths by lower case letters, I got the following equations relating them

$ a + b + c = i + j $

$ a + g + i = j + c $

$ a = g + f $

$ i = g + h $

$ h = f + e $

$ b = e + d $

$ c = d + b $

$ j = d + c $

$ a + g = h + e + b $

$ g + h + d = a + b $

$ e = 12 $

Now it remains to solve this linear system of $11$ equations in the $10$ variables $a$ through $j$.

I did solve the system above, and got a unique solution, which is as follows

$ a = 33 $

$ b = 28 $

$ c = 44 $

$ d = 16 $

$ e = 12  $

$ f = 7 $

$ g = 26 $

$ h = 19 $

$ i = 45 $

$ j = 60 $

And this means that it is possible (in a unique way) to have the above rectangles to be squares with the above side lengths.

I've plotted these values into a to-scale exact figure.

[image]

And my question is:  Can someone please verify these findings and confirm these values ?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The diagram consistencies I checked were OK though I may have missed some. In all it seems OK and width 105 height 104 for the large rectangle tiled by the squares. It would (to me) be worthwhile to draw a to-scale diagram in which all the squares have same apparent width and height on the diagram.

Comment: Your diagram cannot be realized. The solution you get have $i + h > j$. If you allow your $J$ to be smaller, then it is essentially the third simple perfect squared rectangle of order $10$ (the one labeled as 105x104A) documented on [squared net](http://www.squaring.net/sq/sr/spsr/o10/order10_spsr.html) flipped horizontally.

Comment: @achillehui The given diagram is just to show the relative position of the squares.  There is no requirement that $j \gt h + i $.

Comment: In that case, your diagram is realizable and unique (up to symmetry and scaling). There are only six inequivalent spsr (simple perfect squared rectangle) of order 10. you can find them in my previous link to squaring.net.